# Do you know how to make function of cfn-lint fine with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, aws-cloudformation

I use Visual Studio Code to create CloudFormation template.
To detect error in CloudFormation YAML template, I used cfn-lint.

The function of cfn-lint worked well just after starting Visual Studio Code.

Here is good situation.

[image]

However, the function of cfn-lint went wrong soon.
Problems message of cfn-lint(Unresolved tag) disappeared in the screen.

Here is bad situation.

[image]

Do you know how to make function of cfn-lint fine?

Comment: `cfn-lint` appears to still be running even in the second screenshot, since it's highlighting an issue on line 1. Whatever that issue is is probably preventing the rest of the file from being parsed and linted.

Comment: Error message of Line 1 is [cfn-lint]SyntaxError:Unexpected end of JSON input [1,1]. I think that the cause of error is garbled characters. I'm having trouble with how to deal with it.

Comment: Above line 1 it says "cloudformation.json", do you know what that's from?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The "cloudformation.json"  probably shows  the link to aws official documents. I installed vscode-extension of CloudFormation for completing YAML templates and linking to CloudFormation documentation. (https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-template-schema)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a bug with a recent update with cfn-lint. There is a workaround for adding yaml.customTags within VSCode. You can refer more details here: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml/issues/669

```
{
"yaml.customTags": [
    "!Base64 scalar",
    "!Cidr scalar",
    "!And sequence",
    "!Equals sequence",
    "!If sequence",
    "!Not sequence",
    "!Or sequence",
    "!Condition scalar",
    "!FindInMap sequence",
    "!GetAtt scalar",
    "!GetAtt sequence",
    "!GetAZs scalar",
    "!ImportValue scalar",
    "!Join sequence",
    "!Select sequence",
    "!Split sequence",
    "!Sub scalar",
    "!Transform mapping",
    "!Ref scalar",
]
}
```